# JavaScript progressive undefined checks

Tags: javascript, jquery, undefined

Let's say I have the following code:

```
var t = $("#objectID").html();
```

Checking that t is defined and has a proper value is easy.

```
if (typeof(t) === 'undefined' || t == null || t == '')
  t = 'something else';
```

OR

```
var t = $("#objectID").html() || 'something else';
```

My question is though, what if you have something like the following: How would would you check it for undefined values before continuing?

```
$("#object").find("element").html().replace(/ |t/g, '').trim();
```

How do I ensure that each part of the object is legitimate before continuing down the line without having a large block of checks?

What if there's many things similar to .replace and .trim, like 10 or so? How do you check for each one?

Comment: jQuery does that for you already. You only need to check at the end of the chain.

Comment: Regarding your other question (now deleted), use Mutation Observers for a faster response.  It can get pretty messy though and is seldom worth the trouble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the function parameter of `.html()`

```
$("#object").find("element").html(function(html){
   return ((html || 'Something').replace(/ |t/g, '') || 'Something else').trim();
});
```

So, what you are doing is first you're checking html has value and give it some default value if it doesn't have one. Then you group the returned string from replace and check if it has *truthy* value or give it a default value too and then trim it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would do that, checking as needed.

```
var element = $("#object").find("element");
var t = element.length ? element.html() : '';
t = t.replace(/ |t/g, '').trim();
```

First step is making a variable called element to save the jQuery object. Anytime you use the same jQuery search more than once, it's a good idea to save it to a variable: it avoids repetition and speeds up performance.

The next step is calling jQuery's length method to test if it really found any HTML elements. If either "#object" or "element" are not found, element becomes an empty jQuery object with a length of 0, and 0 is considered false in a JavaScript conditional check.

If the length of element is at least 1, then we know it's legitimate, and call safely html() on it.

If length is 0, then t is just set to an empty string. Checking length was necessary because calling html() on an empty jQuery object would have returned undefined instead of a string and caused an error.

I used the ? conditional operator for brevity but you can do the exact same check with an if statement

```
var element = $("#object").find("element");
if (element.length) {
    var t = element.html();
} else {
    var t = '';
}
t = t.replace(/ |t/g, '').trim();
```

I like making t default to an empty string, to ensure the variable is always a string. That way I can call replace() or trim() or any other string method with it.

An empty string also evaluates to false in JavaScript conditions, making it easy to check later on.

```
if (t) {
    doSomethingWith(t);
}
```